# Expression To Test That All Items In Sequence Are The Same

Tags: f#, pattern-matching

Is there a multiple instances pattern in F# somewhere?

Consider that I'm working on a list.  I have the following pattern matching

```
match l with
| [] | [_] -> l  //if the list is empty or contains only one item, simply return it
|        

    //is there a pattern to test if all of the elements are identical?
```

In other words passing [] or [1] should simply return the list and so should [1;1;1;...] but I can't figure out how to pattern match that last pattern.  Is this possible?  Or is there a better approach that I might use? I haven't found anything anywhere about a *repeating* pattern.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't know of any pattern that does what you want, but you could do this:

```
let allSame L =
    match L with
    | [] | [_] -> L
    | h::t when t |> List.forall ((=) h) -> L
    | _ -> failwith "unpossible!" //handle the failing match here
```

P.S. You're talking about a sequence, but your match indicates that you're working with a list. The corresponding code for a sequence would be something like

```
let allSameSeq s = 
    match Seq.length s with
    | 0 | 1 -> s
    | _ when Seq.skip 1 s |> Seq.forall ((=) (Seq.head s)) -> s
    | _ -> failwith "unpossible!"
```

Be warned that the performance of this function may well be worse than the list-based one.

Comment: @cfern, You're right.  I do need to be careful about the terminology I use.  I tend to use "List" and "Sequence" as if they were synonyms--and in F# they're definitely not synonymous.  I am working with a list.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a solution using multi-case active patterns.

```
let (|SingleOrEmpty|AllIdentical|Neither|) (lst:'a list) =
    if lst.Length < 2 then
        SingleOrEmpty
    elif List.forall (fun elem -> elem = lst.[0]) lst then
        AllIdentical
    else
        Neither

let allElementsIdentical lst:'a list =
    match lst with
    |SingleOrEmpty|AllIdentical -> lst
    |Neither -> failwith "Not a suitable list"
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd consider doing one of the following:

```
yourSequence |> Seq.windowed(2) |> Seq.forall(fun arr -> arr.[0] = arr.[1])
```

or

```
let h = Seq.hd yourSequence
yourSequence |> Seq.forall((=) h)
```

It's always good to use library functions when possible ;)